# Page width varies according to Iframe size?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, width

I have a requirement where i need to display a aspx page say login.aspx in two different Iframes of different width without scroll bar.

E.g. Login.aspx should get displayed in iframe of width 800 and 700 without scroll bar. I know I should reduce the UI elements width but the width of the UI elements should vary for Iframes. Is it possible to achieve this with a single Login.aspx by varying the UI elements width according to Iframe width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by dynamically loading the CSS based on Iframe width and height